# null is not object: ( evaluating this.state.email)

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I am creating login form. But having some issue about that problem. this is what I have done so far.

```
loginUser = async(email, password) => {
    if(email != '' && password != ''){
      try {
        let user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
        console.log(user);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      alert("some error")
    }
  }
```

and inside the render:

```
render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Email</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
          value={this.state.email}
        />
        <Text>Password</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
          value={this.state.password}
          secureTextEntry={true}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}
          onPress={() => this.loginUser(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
          <Text>Login!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight style={{backgroundColor: "green"}}
          onPress={()=> this.loginWithFacebook()}>
          <Text>Login with Facebook!</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Because loginUser function not working properly... Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add, this code after the decleration of your class:

```
state = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
}
```

The code is failing because you're trying to get an obj's key which does not exist. You need to creat it first.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the constructor in the code. Try to add this.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    }
  }
```